# Configure Jwt token in Swagger 3.0 in spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am using the a Spring Boot v3.0.2 application for my backend, and I am trying to integration Swagger v3.0 with my application for api documentation purpose. I have successfully configured the swaggerUI with my application, and also able to call the api's(which does not requires JWT/Bearer token) from swagger UI but not able to call the api(which requires JWT/Bearer token). And just for your knowledge, I am able to successfully call the api while passing bearer token from postman.

I have seen some examples on internet that shows a "Authorize" button to set Bearer token on the top of all the api's in SwaggerUI. But all those examples are using Swagger2.0 or lower.

[Authorize button visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4jHD.png)

I had tried to search full internet on how to pass Jwt token from Swagger UI 3.0 and cannot find so.

It would be helpful if someone provide me some ideas or document about how to configure the api to accept JWT token in spring boot 3 and also how can i get a "Authorize" button in Swagger3.0

Answer (score 2):

The Authorize button in the swagger page will only append the authorization header to the request using the credentials you provide, you can enable it by adding the following annotation in your OpenApi config class:

```
@SecurityScheme(
    name = "Bearer Authentication",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    bearerFormat = "JWT",
    scheme = "bearer"
)
```

and then you can apply it to a method / controller by adding

```
@SecurityRequirement(name="Bearer Authentication")
```

As for implementing JWT token auth for your API there are plenty of guides online. [LMGTFY](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=spring%20boot%203%20security%20with%20jwt)

Comment: thanks your answer helped a lot. There are very limited resources available for Swagger3.0 with spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your swagger config

```
@SecurityScheme(
name = "Bearer Authentication",
type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
bearerFormat = "JWT",
scheme = "bearer"
```

)

And Use this on your all controller class

```
@SecurityRequirement(name="Bearer Authentication")
```

And make sure "Bearer Authentication" name will same for both @SecurityRequirement and @SecurityScheme annotation